# run auto_open after the workbook is open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code that runs when the workbook is opened. I try with Auto_open and workbook_open (inside ThisWorkbook object) But I have a problem with both of them. The problem is that the code needs info from the workbook that I am opening As you can see in this peace of code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim fileNam As String
Dim text As String
Dim answer As String
Dim question As String
Dim quesPos As Integer
MsgBox "add-in start"
'On Error GoTo GetOut


fileNam = ThisWorkbook.FullName
jsonFile = Replace(jsonFile, "xls", "survey.descriptor.json")
Open jsonFile For Input As #2
pos = 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Select
'The code gives the error here
```

As the excel file is not already opened it gives an error while getting the name of the file. How can I make to exec the code when it opens but after it is opened?

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.FullName` instead.

Comment: The Workbook_Open() macro seems to work with your code for me with the code that you posted above.

Comment: I test with the workbook_open() but it was not working... I have to say that I am creating an Add-In with that code and then add it to excel. ThisWorkbook.FullName is working but the code continues and it gives me another error. I will put more code to say where it give me the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need some code to run AFTER the workbook is open (rather than "as it is being opened"), one solution would be to create a timed event - set the timer for 5 seconds, trigger it in the auto_open, and have it loop until the file is "properly open". This might look something like this:

In `Auto_Open()`:

```
fullyOpenTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "LetsGo"
```

Then you create another sub that will run once the workbook is open:

```
Sub LetsGo()

On Error Resume Next

' loop around until no error was triggered
Do
  DoEvents
  fileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)  ' "cheap trick" to wait one second
While Err.Number <> 0

On Error GoTo 0
' when you get here, you have an active workbook.
```